# Not able to get Iron router to work on the first time browser back is clicked

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootstrap-modal, iron-router

I am using Iron Router to launch Bootstrap modals from their specific URL in a Meteor project and I want to be able to use the browser back and forward buttons to navigate through them.

**The problem:**

Iron Router doesn't fire on the first time the browser's back button is clicked, after that it works fine!

**My code:**

I simplified the code a little bit but this is how I set the URL when a modal opens or closes(this works).

```
Template.main.events({

    // modal closed -> URL to "/"
    'click.dismiss.bs.modal': function () { 
        if(window.location.pathname != "/"){
            // error prevention: 
            // click.dismiss.bs.modal also fires when user opens a modal
            window.history.pushState("", "", "/");
        }
    },

    // modal opened -> URL to "/u/username"
    'click *[data-target="#infoModal"]': function () { 
        window.history.pushState("", "", "/u/" + username);
    }

});
```

This is my router.js code, also a bit simplified. The console logs do not return the first time the browser's back button is pressed.

```
Router.route('/u/:username', {  
    name: 'u.show',
    waitOn: function () { 
        return Meteor.subscribe('users'); 
    },
    action: function () {
        console.log("Iron Router is trying to open #infoModal");
        $('#infoModal').modal('show');
    }
});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home.show',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('users');
    },
    action: function () {
        console.log("Iron Router is trying to close all modals");
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

I never worked with Iron Router before so I don't really know what I am doing wrong here, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [you need to use `Router.go`](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#using-javascript) rather than manipulating browser history yourself. That way the library can "do the right thing" for its internal bookkeeping.

```
Template.MyButton.events({
  'click #clickme': function () {
    Router.go('/one');
  }
});
```

You should also implement your route check [using iron-router's built in facilities](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#getting-the-current-route) to make your life a little easier:

```
if(Router.current().route.getName() != 'home.show') {
    Router.go('home.show');
}
```

That way if you ever change the URL (like putting the whole app under a subpath) then this code doesn't also have to be changed.

Comment: Thanks! Router.go(); fixed my problem. I also see why your check is better than my example but in the original application I am going to check if the element that is clicked is going to launch a modal or not instead of checking the URL. Your suggestion is probably best practice based on my example though.